# what is cinnamon --replace process?

Tags: command-line, cinnamon, htop

I use cinnamon 3.6.7 <>
`cinnamon --replace` became `cinnamon --replace --replace` when I restarted it:
[image: output of <code>htop</code>]

Comment: Which distro are you using? And do you have just 2GB RAM? Also, the image shows `cinnamon --replace --replace` instead of `cinnamon --replace`.

Comment: cinnamon --replace became cinnamon --replace --replace after I restarted cinnamon

Comment: They are threads

Comment: Try a lighter desktop environment, LXDE or XFCE, instead of cinnamon if you have just 2GB RAM.

Comment: but this doesn't answer the question "What is Cinnamon -- replace"?